# scanf floating numbers doesn't work with %d

Tags: c, numbers, scanf, number-formatting

```
float a = 0.0, b = 0.0;
```

When I do

```
scanf("%f %f", &a, &b);
```

it works but

```
scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
```

doesn't work since a and b are not given the scanned values. Why is that?

Comment: If the argument corresponding to `%d` is not a pointer to int, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

%d is for decimal integer numbers
so you should declare a and b as int.

Comment: I know that, but why does the above not work but when I declare them as ints and use scanf with %f it does work?

Comment: I suggest you try to decompile the C compiler

Comment: Ok, and how will that help me find a solution to my question?

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing undefined behavior.  Although it is utterly pointless to speculate about undefined behavior, probably what is happening is that the bit values corresponding the the integer given on the input stream are put into the variables, but when interpreted as floats they give different values.  That is to say that 0x00000001 may represent the value 1 when interpreted as an integer, that bit sequence has a different value when interpreted as a float.

Comment: Then how can you explain the reverse, if I say int a, b; and then do %f it does work?

Comment: You explain it by understanding the undefined behavior means that anything can happen, even something that matches your expectation.  When the argument type does not match the format string, the behavior is undefined.